# WPF Toolkit DataGrid rendered with incorrect column widths

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a page with lots of components that takes a few seconds to load.

My problem is that the page is rendered before the **DataGrid** components has calculated its column widths and the user can see the rendering on screen.

I built a very simple example: The **DataGrid** has 3 columns, the first column has a `Width="*"`
and the other columns have a fixed width.
The columns with the fixed width are rendered correctly from the beginning, but the star column is rendered with a width of 20.

[image]

After a second the **DataGrid** calculates the correct width of the star column and renders the grid correctly:

[image]

My example XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Controls:DataGrid Name="mainTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="col 0" Width="*">
                <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Col0}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="col 1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" Width="150" />
            <Controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="col 2" Binding="{Binding Col2}" Width="150" />
       </Controls:DataGrid.Columns>
  </Controls:DataGrid>
```

And the code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var rows = new List<RowObj>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        rows.Add(new RowObj
        {
            Col0 = "col0," + i,
            Col1 = "col1," + i,
            Col2 = "col2," + i,
            Col3 = "col3," + i,
            Col4 = "col4," + i,
        });
    }

    mainTable.ItemsSource = rows;
}
```

As a note: I use WpfToolkit (the latest release, from 2010) and .NET 3.5
And I cannot switch to the WPF4 components.

Any idea how to fix the loading issue ?

Comment: Try moving the logic of rows list generation before `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: @RohitVats: doesn't help, It will actually throw an exception in most cases since the controls are not created yet. The actual rendering does not occur at bind time, so setting the data can actually be done in the init or loading events with the same result.

Comment: I meant only move the list part not the assignment - `mainTable.ItemsSource = rows;`. This has to be below `InitializeComponent()` only.

Comment: @RohitVats: you are right, it does help, I will have to also test it with my real program, but if it works this is a correct answer, much better then my hack.

Comment: @RohitVats: unfortunately I cannot test your solution in my application because of the current workflow, but If you make an answer out of your suggestion I will upvote it since it will most likely help others.

Comment: I have converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a new DataGrid that inherits the Toolkit DataGrid, and override the **MeasureOverride** method and set the Widths manually. This way at the first rendering the widths are calculated correctly.

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    double totalWidth = availableSize.Width;
    double absoluteWidth = 0.0;

    DataGridColumn star = null;
    foreach (var col in Columns)
    {
        if (col.Width.IsAbsolute)
        {
            absoluteWidth += col.Width.Value;
            col.MinWidth = col.Width.Value;
        }
        else if (col.Width.IsAuto)
        {
            absoluteWidth += col.Width.DisplayValue;
        }
        else if (col.Width.IsStar)
        {
            if (null == star)
            {
                star = col;
            }
            else
            {
                // This method only handles one star column
                star = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (null != star)
    {
        double diff = totalWidth - absoluteWidth - 4.0;
        if (diff > 0.0)
            star.MinWidth = diff;
        else
            star.MinWidth = 10.0;
    }

    return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
}
```

**WARNING**: this is more of a HACK/Workaround, since it imposes some limitations on the type of column widths I can use, and on the operations I can do on them (for example binding widths is out of the question with this solution).

**NOTE**: for anyone who can load the data before the Page is created, the answer of Rohit Vats will most likely work.

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic of generating list above `InitializeComponent()` and simply set `ItemsSource` afterwards:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var rows = new List<RowObj>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        rows.Add(new RowObj
        {
            Col0 = "col0," + i,
            Col1 = "col1," + i,
            Col2 = "col2," + i,
            Col3 = "col3," + i,
            Col4 = "col4," + i,
        });
    }
    InitializeComponent();

    mainTable.ItemsSource = rows;
}
```

Comment: +1 This will work for anyone who doesn't have to load the data after the creation of the Page. If I could change the workflow of my application this would also be the Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the Code in Dispatcher

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {

                var rows = new List<RowObj>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
                {
                    rows.Add(new RowObj
                    {
                        Col0 = "col0," + i,
                        Col1 = "col1," + i,
                        Col2 = "col2," + i,
                        Col3 = "col3," + i,
                        Col4 = "col4," + i,
                    });
                }

                mainTable.ItemsSource = rows;

            }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: Doesn't help, now the table is shown partially empty and has the resize.